# if the radio input is checked show the next Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

#Jquery

```
        $("input").on('change ', function() {

        var ac_field = $("fieldset .active").children("input[type='radio']:checked");

        if(ac_field){
            var next = ac_field.next("fieldset");

            ac_field.addClass("unactive");
            ac_field.removeClass('active');

            next.addClass("active");
            next.removeClass('unactive');
        }

    })
```

## css

```
    .active{
       display: block;
   }
   .unactive{
       display: none;
   }
```

## html

```
        <!--Q_C1-->
    <fieldset class="Q_C_1 active">
        <legend class="q_holder"></legend>

        <div class="c_cont">

            <div class="C_A C_A_mI">
                <input type="radio" id="C_1_1" class="rad" name="Q_C_1" value="1">

                <label for="C_1_1" class="too_unhappy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A">
                <input type="radio" id="C_1_2" class="rad" name="Q_C_1" value="2">

                <label for="C_1_2" class="unhappy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A">
                <input type="radio" id="C_1_3" class="rad" name="Q_C_1" value="3">

                <label for="C_1_3" class="nut face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A">
                <input type="radio" id="C_1_4" class="rad" name="Q_C_1" value="4">

                <label for="C_1_4" class="happy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A C_A_mII">
                <input type="radio" id="C_1_5" class="rad" name="Q_C_1" value="5">

                <label for="C_1_5" class="too_happy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <span class="stretch"></span>

        </div>

    </fieldset>




    <!--Q_C2-->
    <fieldset class="Q_C_2 unactive">
        <legend class="q_holder"></legend>

        <div class="c_cont">

            <div class="C_A C_A_mI">
                <input type="radio" id="C_2_1" class="rad" name="Q_C_2" value="1">

                <label for="C_1" class="too_unhappy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A">
                <input type="radio" id="C_2_2" class="rad" name="Q_C_2" value="2">

                <label for="C_2_2" class="unhappy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A">
                <input type="radio" id="C_2_3" class="rad" name="Q_C_2" value="3">

                <label for="C_2_3" class="nut face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A">
                <input type="radio" id="C_2_4" class="rad" name="Q_C_2" value="4">

                <label for="C_2_4" class="happy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="C_A C_A_mII">
                <input type="radio" id="C_2_5" class="rad" name="Q_C_2" value="5">

                <label for="C_2_5" class="too_happy face_fix_all"></label>
            </div>

            <span class="stretch"></span>

        </div>

    </fieldset>
```

I want it to check if an input [ radio ] is checked

if there is get any `<fieldset>` (1) element that have child input [ radio ] checked

then get the next `<fieldset>` (2) set its class to active ( display : block )

and `<fieldset>` (1) to inactive ( display :none )

(is the radio input is checked show the next Questions) 
i have 10 `<fieldset>`

Comment: `$('ac_field')` => `$('.ac_field')` and `$('next')` => `$('.next')`

Comment: ac_field => var   and   next => var

Comment: Then you don't need quotes here `$('ac_field')`.

Comment: ac_field is already a jquery object, wrapping it into `$()` again is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script, there are few errors in the way you are using the selectors

```
$("input").on('change ', function() {
   var ac_field = $("input[type='radio']:checked").closest("fieldset.active");//changes here

    if(ac_field){
        var next = ac_field.next("fieldset"); //changes here

        ac_field.addClass("unactive");
        ac_field.removeClass('active');

        next.addClass("active");   //changes here
        next.removeClass('unactive'); //changes here
    }
});
```

Comment: @MoazMabrok https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/oznzgnow/ is this how you want?? I will add it in the answer on your confirmation

Comment: @MoazMabrok Or is it this one you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/oznzgnow/1/

Comment: you added it for the input , i want it for the <fieldset></fieldset>

Comment: @MoazMabrok Yes, I gave you another option too. Please check

Comment: @MoazMabrok Glad I could help